# Triggering a specific keyPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycode

So I want to trigger a 'tab' event on a down keypress, and a 'shift+tab' event on a up keypress. Here's what I've got so far, but I can't seem to set the keyCode of the Keypress event. I read that keyCode was being deprecated, but I tried code also (which does set), but it doesn't trigger the action on input.

```
if (e.keyCode === 38) {
  // trigger a shift tab
  console.log('up key was pressed')
}

if (e.keyCode === 40) {
  console.log('down key was pressed')
  let event = new KeyboardEvent('keyPress', { keyCode: 9 })
  window.dispatchEvent(event)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to tab between multiple fields e.g. back and forth in a set of inputs?

Comment: you need to use keydown for these

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lv9bthd/18/  to capture up and down arrow presses you need keydown, can't use keypress

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    console.log('up key was pressed');
  }
});
```